# Create a new DB instance in Amazon CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I have developed the application using Java and I also used the Amazon PostgreSQL database for data management. I hosted the application in Elastic beanstalk. Now, Someone suggested me to use the Amazon CloudFormation. So I created the Infrastructure code in JSON Format that also include Amazon RDS but I have some doubts.

When I use CloudFormation then that will automatically creates the new DB instance for my application but I specified another DB instance name in Java code then how it will communicate?

Please help me to clarify the doubts.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Not sure what is the issue? Just the same in java and CFN? Either change Java code or CFN template.

Comment: I want to communicate with new database but not old database. Then how to change it into Java code. If I want to change the new database then I need endpoint for the database so that only I can change it from Java code. During the CloudFormation infrastructure how can I get the new endpoint.

Comment: Can you provide your CFN template code. Its difficult to speculate on what you may or may not have in your template.

Comment: "MyDB" : {
 "Type" : "AWS::RDS::DBInstance",
 "Properties" : {
     "DBSecurityGroups" : [
        {"Ref" : "MyDbSecurityByEC2SecurityGroup"}, {"Ref" : "MyDbSecurityByCIDRIPGroup"} ],
     "AllocatedStorage" : "5",
     "DBInstanceClass" : "db.t2.small",
     "Engine" : "PostgreSQL",
     "MasterUsername" : "MyName",
     "MasterUserPassword" : "MyPassword"
 },
 "DeletionPolicy" : "Snapshot"
}

Answer (score 0):

You can configure DB URL in outputs section of CFN so that you get the required URL

[CFN outputs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html)

Answer (score 0):

To get endpoint url for your [AWS::RDS::DBInstance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html) is returned using [Return values](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html#aws-properties-rds-database-instance-return-values):

> **Endpoint.Address**  The connection endpoint for the database. For example: mystack-mydb-1apw1j4phylrk.cg034hpkmmjt.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com

> **Endpoint.Port**  The port number on which the database accepts connections. For example: 3306

To get the `Endpoint.Address` out of your stack, you have to add [Outputs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html) section to your template. En example would be:

```
    "Outputs": {
        "DBEndpoint": {
            "Description": "Endpoint for my RDS Instance",
            "Value": {
                 "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "MyDB", "Endpoint.Address" ]}
            }
        }
    }
```

Then using **AWS SDK for Java** you can query the Outputs of your CFN Stack to use in your Java application.

Comment: I have include the above script in our file and create the database but I don't have any idea about how to query the Outputs in my java application. Would you please suggest?

Comment: I have developed my java application using Spring boot framework. I have include my database endpoint in application.properties file.

Comment: Java has [getOutputs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cloudformation/model/Stack.html#getOutputs--) to get outputs from a stack. So you can use that.